# Android development with sqlite: How to use string result from a database query without using a listview?

Tags: android, string, sqlite, cursor

I've been working on this for days, off and on. What I want to do is when a user clicks on a button, run a query against my sql lite database that returns 1 value (happens to be an integer, but string is fine), which I can then put into a text box.  (Also When the user changes input values, and clicks the button, they get a different result.

I have gone through a ton of examples, but they all use a listview at the end to display a set of rows.  Is there a way to take the results from my database adapter, which I thought was a string .
In my code from mydbadapter below, I would like to return a value from KEY_FEE column:

```
public String getdata(){
 String[] columns = new String[]{KEY_ROWID, KEY_SPEED, KEY_TIME, KEY_FEE };
 Cursor c = myDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE, columns, "speed like '25' AND "
         + "time like '50'", null, null, null, null);
 String result ="";
 int iRow =c.getColumnIndex(KEY_ROWID);
int iSPEED =c.getColumnIndex(KEY_SPEED);
int iTIME=c.getColumnIndex(KEY_TIME);
int iFEE =c.getColumnIndex(KEY_FEE);

for (c.moveToFirst(); !c.isAfterLast();c.moveToNext()){
    result = result + c.getString(iRow) + " " +c.getString(iSPEED) + " " 
    +c.getString(iTIME)  + " " +c.getString(iFEE) + "/n";
}
 return result;    }
```

IS this **result** actually a string?

If so, how can I access it from my main program, upon button click:
            Button.OnClickListener buttonOnClickListener = new Button.OnClickListener(){

```
         @Override
       public void onClick(View v) {
            System.out.println("The calculate FEE button was clicked " );

            //TODO
            //getdata here from database, to a variable for lineout, sub in for "60".
            //
            myDbHelper.getdata();
            //set the stringVal variable to the Fee
            _stringVal = "Fee is:" **???how to specify the result string from dbhelper here?**;
            //sets the text textview based on prior code: _value = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3);
            _value.setText(_stringVal);

            //System.out.println("Text should say "+_stringVal);
            // System.out.println("Get Data Has been called. ");
       }
    };
```

Comment: String result = myDbHelper.getdata();
            //set the stringVal variable to the Fee
            _stringVal = "Fee is:" **???result**; you can try this..

Comment: Welcome to SO!  If one of the answers below solved your issue, or lead to to getting it solved, you should accept it (click the check mark next to the appropriate answer).  That does two things.  It lets everyone know your issue has been resolved, and it gives the person that helps you credit for the assist.  Good luck withyour app!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes **result** is a string. you set that as a string so it is a string.

If you want to get the values of one column only why did you put all the columns values in to result string.

```
for (c.moveToFirst(); !c.isAfterLast();c.moveToNext()){
    result = result + c.getString(iRow) + " " +c.getString(iSPEED) + " " 
    +c.getString(iTIME)  + " " +c.getString(iFEE) + "/n";
}
```

to get that value to your click event

```
_stringVal = myDbHelper.getdata();
```

according to your query and the values on the data base some times you might get more than one row of data.
then your **result** may be very long and contains lots of values. If you need to display only this is ok but if you need to do more calculations using these valus this is not a good idea.

Comment: If you want to get the values of one column only why did you put all the columns values in to result string.

Comment: PERFECT!  Didnt realize how close I was.  Now some grunt work on the database side, some user testing and maybe I can get my very first app 'live' on market this weekend!!! Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: THANKS for your response.     Yes, I could change the sql for the final version... I just wanted to see the values together.  I will remove the other items, and just show the FEE..  

But in your example above, how do I produce the resulting string?
string=?

Comment: Ok if you want to get only one column you can pul out data from only one column. To produce the resulting string you need only assign the values from database to **result** string. I think you should learn more about java and programming. just follow some tutorials, If need any help for that please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

You should consider improving your Java knowledge before venturing further into Android development. There are a lot of tutorials and resources available on the web that will help you in this.

To answer your question:

> IS this result actually a string?

Yes, `String result ="";` tells you that `result` is a `String` object reference.

> In my code from mydbadapter below, I would like to return a value from KEY_FEE column:

Your code does much more than returning just the KEY_FEE column. It concatenates 4 column values from several results (all results that match your SQL query) into a single string.

> _stringVal = "Fee is:" **???how to specify the result string from dbhelper here?**;

This is how you do it:

```
//set the stringVal variable to the Fee
_stringVal = myDbHelper.getdata();
```

Comment: PERFECT! Thanks a lot.  Didnt realize how close I was.  Now some grunt work on the database side, some user testing and maybe I can get my very first app 'live' on market this weekend!!!

Comment: Yes, I am a beginner and trying to learn java as well.  IMO, hands on is the best way to learn.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm mis-understanding, but you say you only want the value from the KEY_FEE column, so why are you concatenating all that data if all you want is the one bit?  Or all of the one bits?

```
Cursor c = myDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE, columns, "speed like '25' AND " 
     + "time like '50'", null, null, null, null); 

c.moveToFirst();
String[] feeArray = new String[c.getcount()]
int i=0;    
while (c.isAfterLast() == false) {
    feeArray[i] = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(KEY_FEE));     
    i++;
    c.moveToNext();
}
```

The above will put a KEY_FEE value into the string array for each record returned by the cursor.

Comment: Yes, I will change the sql... I just wanted to see the values together.  I will remove the other items, and just show the FEE.(Didnt realize how close I was to the answer, but I would not have gotten the syntax without this help).  THANKS.     Now some grunt work on the database side, some user testing and maybe I can get my very first app 'live' on market this weekend!!!